# SilverStripe SilverShop Shipping - Disabling distance shipping method

Tags: php, silverstripe, silverstripe-4, silvershop

I've set up an ecommerce site using the SilverShop add-on which utilises SilverStripe Shipping.

Whenever I try to run this on a remote server (such as the production copy of the site), I get an error related to `silvershop/geocoding`, which is a requirement of the `silvershop/shipping` library for the `DistanceShippingMethod` feature.

The error is as follows:

> [Emergency] Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Geocoder\Model\AddressCollection::toArray()
>
> GET /
>
> Line 43 in ...\vendor\silvershop\geocoding\src\Extensions\GeocodedUserInfo.php

This error doesn't appear on localhost as the `$ip` variable is `null`, so line 43 is skipped. It's only when you're connecting using an external IP does the error appear.

I've tried disabling this extension to get around the issue by using `remove_extension` in both _config.php and mysite.yml, but with no joy. I've also used the config suggested by *silvershop/geocoding*:

```
SilverShop\Model\Address:
  enable_geocoding: false
```

But this doesn't stop that particular line being run, so doesn't resolve the issue.

So, my next step would be to disable the `DistanceShippingMethod` completely, as it's not used by this site anyway. But I can't see how to do this.

Any pointers on how to either fix the initial error, or how to disable that specific feature, would be very much welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [issue](https://github.com/silvershop/silvershop-geocoding/issues/14) has now been fixed on the SilverShop Geocoding module GitHub repository:
https://github.com/silvershop/silvershop-geocoding/commit/c225ae7369f81098bfb38c0e8b3f9160ffacdfcf

Update the module, deploy that fix and this issue should be resolved.

Comment: Thank you @3dgoo! That was a pretty swift response in fixing it, fair play!

Comment: Good job finding the existing issue on GitHub and bumping it.